How to get the response from the AI Model
I adapted this code from https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/llama-cpp-tutorial
from llama_cpp import Llama
# GLOBAL VARIABLES
my_model_path = "./model/zephyr-7b-beta.Q4_0.gguf"
CONTEXT_SIZE = 512

# LOAD THE MODEL
zephyr_model = Llama(model_path=my_model_path,
                    n_ctx=CONTEXT_SIZE)

def generate_text_from_prompt(user_prompt,
                             max_tokens = 100,
                             temperature = 0.3,
                             top_p = 0.1,
                             echo = True,
                             stop = ["Q", "\n"]):

   # Define the parameters
   model_output = zephyr_model(
       user_prompt,
       max_tokens=max_tokens,
       temperature=temperature,
       top_p=top_p,
       echo=echo,
       stop=stop,
   )
   return model_output

if __name__ == "__main__":

   my_prompt = "What do you think about fishing for catfish?"

   zephyr_model_response = generate_text_from_prompt(my_prompt)

   final_result = zephyr_model_response["choices"][0]["text"].strip()
   print(final_result)

How do I print the response to the prompt? It prints a huge amount of information but I don't see the response.
When I print model_output I get
{'id': 'cmpl-f13d4d89-5f25-4c01-b274-97df4ebaba84', 'object': 'text_completion', 'created': 1715958626, 'model': './model/zephyr-7b-beta.Q4_0.gguf', 'choices': [{'text': 'What do you think about fishing for catfish?', 'index': 0, 'logprobs': None, 'finish_reason': 'stop'}], 'usage': {'prompt_tokens': 11, 'completion_tokens': 1, 'total_tokens': 12}}


Any error? Just print model_output, what does it say? Your code should work.

@Daviid No error that I recognize as an error. If the model is unhappy, I can't tell.
I added to the question demonstrating when I get when I print model_response.

You didn't adapt the code properly. Printing the model_output is not enough. You should print model_output["choices"][0]["text"].strip() which, according to documentation, prints the answer.
However, in your case it printed the question which is a different problem. Try asking again more precise question. Something like, why is my model printing questions instead of answers.

@JaK I adapted that print statement verbatim.

The answer is... the code is correct. Sometimes the model simply doesn't generate an answer, due to the nature of the model and the arguments provided with the prompt.
If I change the top_p and temperature arguments to be the the most forgiving and random:
def generate_text_from_prompt(user_prompt,
                             max_tokens = None,
                             temperature = 1,
                             top_p = 1,
                             echo = True,
                             stop = ["Q", "\n"]):

and I prompt the model 50 times:
for i in range(0, 50):
  my_prompt = "What is a bass?"
  zephyr_model_response = generate_text_from_prompt(my_prompt)
  final_result = zephyr_model_response["choices"][0]["text"].strip()
  print(i, ":", final_result)

Sometimes we get answers and sometimes we don't:
0 : What is a bass?
1 : What is a bass?
2 : What is a bass?
3 : What is a bass?
4 : What is a bass?
5 : What is a bass? It’s simple: A bass is the lowest sounding instrument in an orchestra, usually tuned to an E. However, a lot of people aren’t quite sure how to classify the double bass, and where exactly it should fall in the musical world.
6 : What is a bass?
7 : What is a bass?
8 : What is a bass?
9 : What is a bass? The word "bass" derives from the Greek 'basso' meaning deep or low. But what defines a bass as a bass?
10 : What is a bass?
11 : What is a bass? The word itself conjures up images of big, lumpish beasts with long-slung guitars and deep voices. But while the likes of Steve Harris and Glenn Hughes have fitted that description down the years, what about those bass players who don't necessarily fit into that mould?
12 : What is a bass?
13 : What is a bass?
14 : What is a bass?
15 : What is a bass? The common carp (Cyprinus carpio) is the species most usually meant by carpers and anglers talking or composing about “bass”. However, it isn’t a member of the bass family (Moronidae). Carps are members of the minnow family (Cyprinidae) along with many other kinds.
16 : What is a bass?

